# Drawer comes little late using MCPanelViewController

Tags: ios, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I used [MCPanelViewController](https://github.com/mehsome/MCPanelViewController/) in an iOS app for drawing left and right controllers (As android has inbuilt control drawer). It works good but it does not come with gesture it comes little late. if anyone had an answer to problem it would be great.

This is the code in `UIViewController (MCPanelViewControllerInternal)` category:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {
    // initialization for screen edge pan gesture
    if ([pan isKindOfClass:[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer class]] &&
        pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        __weak UIViewController *controller = objc_getAssociatedObject(pan, &MCPanelViewGesturePresentingViewControllerKey);

        if (!controller) {
            return;
        }

        MCPanelAnimationDirection direction = [objc_getAssociatedObject(pan, &MCPanelViewGestureAnimationDirectionKey) integerValue];
        [self setupController:controller withDirection:direction];

        CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:pan.view];
        CGFloat width = direction == MCPanelAnimationDirectionLeft ? translation.x : -1 * translation.x;

        [self layoutSubviewsToWidth:0];
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:MCPanelViewAnimationDuration delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
            [strongSelf layoutSubviewsToWidth:width];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];

        CGFloat offset = self.maxWidth - width;
        if (direction == MCPanelAnimationDirectionLeft) {
            offset *= -1;
        }
        [pan setTranslation:CGPointMake(offset, translation.y) inView:pan.view];
    }

    if (!self.parentViewController) {
        return;
    }

    CGFloat newWidth = [pan translationInView:pan.view].x;
    if (self.direction == MCPanelAnimationDirectionRight) {
        newWidth *= -1;
    }
    newWidth += self.maxWidth;
    CGFloat ratio = newWidth / self.maxWidth;

    switch (pan.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            [self layoutSubviewsToWidth:newWidth];
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled: {
            CGFloat threshold = MCPanelViewGestureThreshold;

            // invert threshold if we started a screen edge pan gesture
            if ([pan isKindOfClass:[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                threshold = 1 - threshold;
            }

            if (ratio < threshold) {
                [self dismiss];
            }
            else {
                __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
                [UIView animateWithDuration:MCPanelViewAnimationDuration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
                    [strongSelf layoutSubviewsToWidth:strongSelf.maxWidth];
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                }];
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by " it does not come with gesture it comes little late"? do you mean the gestures are recognized a bit late than usual? can you post your code so far ?

Comment: yes you are right gesture are recognized little late that could be too

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/matthewcheok/MCPanelViewController/issues/8) of the library.

To quote matthewcheok:

> The delay is mainly due to way the panel captures the background image to apply the image blur in advance. It does this exactly once, when the gesture is triggered or when opened programatically, and then crops the image using UIView content modes, to show only the relevant parts obscured by the panel.